# Unable to receive subscription acknowledgement for vsomeip client

Tags: c++, udp, automotive

I have used the code from subscribe-sample.cpp provided in vsomeip examples with little modification based on our requirement. Currently, subscribing to a single message. The server is a proprietary solution which also uses Genivi vsomeip with Common API binding. The client is registered but the subscription acknowledgement is not received.

```
// Copyright (C) 2014-2017 Bayerische Motoren Werke Aktiengesellschaft (BMW AG)
// This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
// License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
// file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
#ifndef VSOMEIP_ENABLE_SIGNAL_HANDLING
#include <csignal>
#endif
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

#include <vsomeip/vsomeip.hpp>

#define SAMPLE_SERVICE_ID       0xD101
#define SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID      0x0001
#define SAMPLE_METHOD_ID        0x8050

#define SAMPLE_EVENT_ID         0x8050
#define SAMPLE_GET_METHOD_ID    0x0001
#define SAMPLE_SET_METHOD_ID    0x0002

#define SAMPLE_EVENTGROUP_ID    0x0001

#define OTHER_SAMPLE_SERVICE_ID 0x0248
#define OTHER_SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID 0x5422
#define OTHER_SAMPLE_METHOD_ID  0x1421

class client_sample {
public:
    client_sample(bool _use_tcp) :
        app_(vsomeip::runtime::get()->create_application()), use_tcp_(
            _use_tcp) {
    }

    bool init() {
        if (!app_->init()) {
            std::cerr << "Couldn't initialize application" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        std::cout << "Client settings [protocol="
            << (use_tcp_ ? "TCP" : "UDP")
            << "]"
            << std::endl;

        app_->register_state_handler(
            std::bind(&client_sample::on_state, this,
                std::placeholders::_1));

        app_->register_message_handler(
            vsomeip::ANY_SERVICE, SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID, vsomeip::ANY_METHOD,
            std::bind(&client_sample::on_message, this,
                std::placeholders::_1));

        app_->register_availability_handler(SAMPLE_SERVICE_ID, SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID,
            std::bind(&client_sample::on_availability,
                this,
                std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));

        std::set<vsomeip::eventgroup_t> its_groups;
        its_groups.insert(SAMPLE_EVENTGROUP_ID);
        app_->request_event(
            SAMPLE_SERVICE_ID,
            SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID,
            SAMPLE_EVENT_ID,
            its_groups,
            vsomeip::event_type_e::ET_EVENT);
        app_->subscribe(SAMPLE_SERVICE_ID, SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID, SAMPLE_EVENTGROUP_ID, 0x00, SAMPLE_EVENT_ID);

        return true;
    }

    void start() {
        app_->start();
    }

#ifndef VSOMEIP_ENABLE_SIGNAL_HANDLING
    /*
    * Handle signal to shutdown
    */
    void stop() {
        app_->clear_all_handler();
        app_->unsubscribe(SAMPLE_SERVICE_ID, SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID, SAMPLE_EVENTGROUP_ID);
        app_->release_event(SAMPLE_SERVICE_ID, SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID, SAMPLE_EVENT_ID);
        app_->release_service(SAMPLE_SERVICE_ID, SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID);
        app_->stop();
    }
#endif

    void on_state(vsomeip::state_type_e _state) {
        if (_state == vsomeip::state_type_e::ST_REGISTERED) {
            app_->request_service(SAMPLE_SERVICE_ID, SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID);
        }
    }

    void on_availability(vsomeip::service_t _service, vsomeip::instance_t _instance, bool _is_available) {
        std::cout << "Service ["
            << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << _service << "." << _instance
            << "] is "
            << (_is_available ? "available." : "NOT available.")
            << std::endl;
    }

    void on_message(const std::shared_ptr<vsomeip::message> &_response) {
        std::stringstream its_message;
        its_message << "Received a notification for Event ["
            << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex
            << _response->get_service() << "."
            << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex
            << _response->get_instance() << "."
            << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex
            << _response->get_method() << "] to Client/Session ["
            << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex
            << _response->get_client() << "/"
            << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex
            << _response->get_session()
            << "] = ";
        std::shared_ptr<vsomeip::payload> its_payload =
            _response->get_payload();
        its_message << "(" << std::dec << its_payload->get_length() << ") ";
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < its_payload->get_length(); ++i)
            its_message << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
            << (int)its_payload->get_data()[i] << " ";
        std::cout << its_message.str() << std::endl;

        if (_response->get_client() == 0) {
            if ((its_payload->get_length() % 5) == 0) {
                std::shared_ptr<vsomeip::message> its_get
                    = vsomeip::runtime::get()->create_request();
                its_get->set_service(SAMPLE_SERVICE_ID);
                its_get->set_instance(SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID);
                its_get->set_method(SAMPLE_GET_METHOD_ID);
                its_get->set_reliable(use_tcp_);
                app_->send(its_get);
            }

            if ((its_payload->get_length() % 8) == 0) {
                std::shared_ptr<vsomeip::message> its_set
                    = vsomeip::runtime::get()->create_request();
                its_set->set_service(SAMPLE_SERVICE_ID);
                its_set->set_instance(SAMPLE_INSTANCE_ID);
                its_set->set_method(SAMPLE_SET_METHOD_ID);
                its_set->set_reliable(use_tcp_);

                const vsomeip::byte_t its_data[]
                    = { 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47,
                    0x48, 0x49, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52 };
                std::shared_ptr<vsomeip::payload> its_set_payload
                    = vsomeip::runtime::get()->create_payload();
                its_set_payload->set_data(its_data, sizeof(its_data));
                its_set->set_payload(its_set_payload);
                app_->send(its_set);
            }
        }
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr< vsomeip::application > app_;
    bool use_tcp_;
};

#ifndef VSOMEIP_ENABLE_SIGNAL_HANDLING
client_sample *its_sample_ptr(nullptr);
void handle_signal(int _signal) {
    if (its_sample_ptr != nullptr &&
        (_signal == SIGINT || _signal == SIGTERM))
        its_sample_ptr->stop();
}
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    bool use_tcp = false;
    putenv("VSOMEIP_APPLICATION_NAME=client_sample");
    putenv("VSOMEIP_CONFIGURATION_FILE_PATH=C:/Users/gjdwf9/Downloads/vsomeip-master/test/vsomeip-udp-client.json");
    client_sample its_sample(use_tcp);
#ifndef VSOMEIP_ENABLE_SIGNAL_HANDLING
    its_sample_ptr = &its_sample;
    signal(SIGINT, handle_signal);
    signal(SIGTERM, handle_signal);
#endif
    if (its_sample.init()) {
        its_sample.start();
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

[The screen grab of the client seen during execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rwmf.png)

Can someone please help if I am making some mistake when calling subscribe API or if it is something else. The last message seen is the availability, we are also not able to see the message that the client is connected.

Comment: There is a permission denied accessing/creating the vsomeip lock. Please check this one.